# mysql combine 2 columns where condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table friends with 4 columns (id, sender, receiver, status) and I need a query that will unite (reunion, I dont know the word in english) the sender and receiver colums where the sender and the receiver are equal to lets say 2.
For example the table looks like this

```
| sender | receiver |
|    2   |   10     |
|    2   |    8     |
|    2   |    9     |
|    6   |    2     |
|    7   |    3     |
|    10  |    3     |
```

And after the query it will show: (the first 3 rows are shown because the sender = 2, then the forth row is show because the receiver is 2. The rest of the rows are not shown)

```
| result |
|   10   |
|    8   |
|    9   |
|    6   |
```

Comment: well, because I need it as you can see in the result table, to include only the values that respect the condition of sender or/and receiver (dont know) are equal to 2.

Comment: nevermind the question. i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the right keyword; UNION will let you do what you want.

```
SELECT `receiver` as `result` FROM `table` WHERE `sender` = 2
UNION
SELECT `sender` as `result` FROM `table` WHERE `receiver` = 2
```

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
case when sender = 2
then receiver
else sender
end
from friends
where sender = 2 or receiver = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, I hope has sense to you:

```
Select sender as result
from friends
where receiver = 2
union
Select receiver as result
from friends
where sender = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT sender as iResult
    FROM   friends
    WHERE  receiver = 2
         UNION
    SELECT receiver as result
    FROM friends
    WHERE sender = 2) c
 ORDER BY c.iResult DESC
```